# How to forwarded cookies to the clound function when deploying SvelteKit to Firebase hosting (via experiments:enable webframeworks)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, sveltekit

##### Problem

I am trying to deploy my sveltkit app to firebase using the new webframeworks extension. This specifically creates a single cloud function (<Project>-ioaru263ga-ew.a.run.app) that runs the server logic.

The actual app has the domain <Project>.web.app. When i run both parts on localhost (using firebase emulators:start) everything works fine. When i deploy it however no cookies reach the server.

---

##### What I tried

Setting a cookie with the cloud functions domain and then calling the cloud function directly does however work.

That cookies can not be passed to another domain makes sense to me, but how do I solve the problem properly.

Is there a way to make the server domain a subdomain of the app (api.<project>.web.app)? Rewrites maybe but not sure how to force the sveltkit app to use that new route. Or is it possible to force forwarding with hooks? Or should I try to set appropriate CORS headers.

I am not too familiar with this topic yet.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that google cloud functions only allow a single cookie named "__session". Renaming resolved my Problem.